# Convert string variable (in xml format) as part of the final xml

Tags: xslt

I'm having in a xsl file a variable (`varXml`) which actually retains an xml -like this: `<apps><det id="aaaa"><det key="name"><det id="12"/><tur key="34" id="00x"/></det></det></apps>`.

The format of the xsl file looks like this:

```
<xsl:element name="opersApps">
   <xsl:attribute name="sts">1</xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:value-of select="$varXml"/>
</xsl:element>
```

And the result is:

```
<opersApps sts="1">
```

*`<apps><det id="aaaa"><det key="name"><det id="12"/><tur key="34" id="00x"/></det></det></apps>`*

```
</opersApps>
```

Now looks like [here](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_gaTNvavlLC4/TT3Hu52rlnI/AAAAAAAACmg/VHGw-AJKcuA/s800/xml.jpg).

The middle part (variable varXml) not look at an xml. How can it be integrated to be part of the xml?
I want to look like this:

```
<opersApps sts="1">
<apps>
    <det id="aaaa">
        <det key="name">
            <det id="12"/>
            <tur key="34" id="00x"/>
        </det>
    </det>         
</apps>
</opersApps>
```

Thanks.

Later edit:
varXml looks like this:

```
 String varXml ="<det id=\"aaaa\">\n" +
                "    <det key=\"name\">\n" +
                "        <det id=\"12\"/>\n" +
                "        <tur key=\"34\" id=\"00x\"/>\n" +
                "    </det>\n" +
                "</det> ";
```

Comment: It is a well-formatted xml. are you missing the new lines?

Comment: Are you looking for control over indentation?

Comment: @ChrisJ: yes! I've put a link with the actual result - which is not what I want to look like.

Comment: Did you try <xsl:output method = "xml" indent = "yes" />

Comment: @Paul: the layout of an XML file is not significant. XML processors do not always honor the options of <xsl:output>, so maybe you had better post-process your file for readability with a pretty printer such as xmllint. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Pretty_Printer

Comment: What is the value of varXml? The value-of element returns the concatenated string content of the text descendants. So if your varXml is a series of nodes suggested by your first line its value is the empty string. Or does your varXml include quoted xml (which will be messy and cannot easily be formatted)?

Comment: @ChrisJ: is not just the layout... I've edit the actual xml format and the italic part is actually look like that - like in the picture which link I've putted below.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: I've edit the post with the actual value of varXml variable. The varXml inlcudes quotes .. Should I modifie the format of varXml before send it to xsl file? I've tried with concatenated string but is the same output...

Comment: @Vijay Sirigiri: yes , I've tried.I have something like:     <xsl:output
            method="xml"
            version="1.0"
            encoding="utf-8"
            omit-xml-declaration="no"
            indent="yes"/>

Comment: @Paul: From your last edit, it looks like you are passing a **string data type parameter** to the XSLT processor. If that's the case, then you won't have an XML "fragment" but a string, and it should be output as a **text node**. There is not going to be a built-in function for parsing until XSLT/XPath 3.0

Comment: @Alejandro: exactly ...I expressed wrong; So, there is no way to parse that string data type parameter as an xml? I really need this to do.. Maybe transform the varXml ?!

Comment: Did you try <xsl:copy-of select="$varXml"/>? Sorry, your image is broken now.

Comment: @Paul: I'm sure that the enviroment calling the XSLT processor has an XML parser implementation. So, you need to parse (or to build) your XML first, and then to pass it to the XSLT processor as node set data type, **mostly the same way you do with your input source**.

Comment: @Paul: See my answer for a number of alternative solutions. I recommend that the definition of the variable be modified so that it contains real XML -- not text.

Comment: @Paul - glad that we have identified that your varXml is a STRING, not a node. I agree with the others that you should never try to work with strings of XML if possible. Heed what Michael Kay says - he is one of the world's top XML/XSLT gurus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches.

(a) parse the XML string into a tree, and then manipulate it as a tree using XSLT instructions (for example, xsl:copy-of). There's no standard way of parsing an XML string from within XSLT, but many products have extensions (e.g. saxon:parse()) or allow you to write your own.

(b) copy the XML string to the serialized output, using disable-output-escaping="yes". This won't work in all environments - it depends on the processor supporting the feature and on you running in an environment that uses the XSLT processor's serializer. But it's one of the few use-cases where disable-output-escaping can be justified.

Comment: Thank you all. I resolved this in a different way - with a recursively statement in the transformer xsl file and without having a String variable in xml format.

Answer (score 2):

**Such conversion is not possible in pure XSLT/XPath** (ver. 1.0 and 2.0).

**The best recommendation**: Never to represent a XML document or fragment as string -- this destroys the markup and flattens it to a one-dimensional text.

**In case it is not possible to change the value of the variable** to contain real markup, then one needs to pass this variable to an extension function, that would parse the string and return back a real XML document.

**Another possible solution is to use the `disable-output-escaping` attribute**, but this is not guaranteed to work on all XSLT processors and grossly violates the XSLT architectural model.

**I recommend to always avoid using DOE**.

Comment: Thaknks first. I've tried with d.o.e but didn't worked. How I can pass the variable to an extension function which should parse the string into xml doc.? (soryy, I'm very very new in using xsl..)

Comment: @Paul: You need to write an extension function. The ways how this can be done depend on the XSLT processor you are using. You need to read the appropriate documentation of your XSLT processor. Or ask a new question about how to write an extension function for your particular XSLT processor. I know how to do this for the standard .NET XSLT processors, but not for many other XSLT processors.